# What kind of motor should I get for a portable fan?

Tags: dc-motor, fan

My 9 V DC motor got damaged. It is a 9 V (6 DD batteries). It draws about 420 mA.
I measure the length, diameter, shaft diameter, screws diameter, etc and bought one 6-12 V that fits perfectly, but I didn't read the new DC motor specs. It said 1.2 A at no load.
And after I put the propeller it draws about 3.5 A (the propeller is plastic and very light, I don't know why it doubles its current).

What kind of motor should I get and the faster RPM the better? Or not necessarily?

Thanks

Comment: The load controls the motor speed so that controls the current. Research and choose a different motor.

Comment: That sounds like a very inefficient (or bad) motor. You also need to determine the optimal fan speed - probably only a couple thousand RPM unless it's a really tiny fan.

Comment: Those portable fan rarely has a part number or code. So i 'm guessing only by the size of the motor body. But I dont know the RPM (i could guess about 6000 rpm). If i get another 9v say: 80ma without load and say 10000rpm, will it be much stronger (the breeze)?

Comment: Once at stationary speed, the weight of the propeller makes no difference, only the shape of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The load on the motor depends on the fan and speed.

The speed you should choose depends on the fan.

You are not loading the motor with a "light plastic fan" you are loading the motor with the amount of air you are moving.

In theory the fan was designed for the speed of the motor. As this is probably a cheap and dirty fan, the chances of the company spending much time matching the fan and the motor is slim. So anything vaugly similar would probably be fine.

Comment: So, a motor that exceeds the RPM of the original will be good (if the current consumption is adequate)?

Comment: No, the power requirement of a fan increases as the CUBE of speed. So doubling RPM needs 8* the power. You need to match the original RPM quite closely.

Comment: Please forgive me ignorance, you mean doubling the RPM needs eight times the power?